# Same coordinate system yet spatial reference does not match data frame

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, cogo

My primary duty is to COGO and need my results to be perfect.
I have my data frame properties in NAD 83 State Plane California V FIPS (picture below).
[image: Data Frame Properties]

Here is my COGO layer image showing the same thing.
[image: COGO layer]

They are in the exact same coordinate system, so why am I still receiving the spatial reference does not match data frame?

[image: Spatial reference does not match error.]

Comment: This is an issue probably better taken up with Tech Support, but it probably has to do with the exact string used to define the coordinate system. Please [Edit] the question to provide the exact release of ArcGIS in use, and the full coordinate reference string for at least two layers.

Comment: They are not showing the same thing, look closely at the coordinate system names.  Your dataframe uses NAD 1983 (2011), and your layer uses regular NAD 1983, so there is a datum conflict

Comment: In other words "NAD_1983_2011_StatePlane_California_V_FIPS_0405_Ft_US" is different from "NAD_1983_StatePlane_California_V_FIPS_0405_Feet"

Comment: @SamSzotkowski Sam I feel silly. Thank you for the assistance, I put the data frame to match the COGO layer. Would it be best to put them all in the 2011 version as it is newer, or does that not matter?

Comment: @SamSzotkowski I have them all in NAD_1983_StatePlane_California_V_FIPS_0405_Feet

Comment: @SamSzotkowski Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: @tmo looks like you're working with municipal data so I'd go with the coordinate system their GIS department chose.  If you had some application where extremely high accuracy was a critical requirement, maybe like measuring continental drift, then you would be much more careful about which datum/geoid your projection uses.  But for your purposes, I'm sure as long as you pick California State Plane 5 then the different datums will have negligible impact on your results.  I believe we're talking distortions on the order of 1:10,000 or thereabouts, but don't quote me on that.

Answer (score 1):

They are not showing the same thing, look closely at the coordinate system names. Your dataframe uses "NAD_1983_2011_StatePlane_California_V_FIPS_0405_Ft_US" ([WKID:6424](https://epsg.io/6424)), which is different from "NAD_1983_StatePlane_California_V_FIPS_0405_Feet" ([WKID:2229](https://epsg.io/2229)) in your layer.  These names indicate that your dataframe uses NAD 1983 (2011), and your layer uses regular NAD 1983, so there is a datum conflict.

For additional context, there are multiple versions of most State Plane coordinate systems, with newer ones using more accurate/updated datums.  Oftentimes your data dictates which one you should use; I don't usually care about centimeter precision and in a situation like yours I'd rather just change the dataframe's coordinate system since your layers all already match.

Whether the small improvement from NAD 1983 to NAD 1983(2011) matters depends on your application, but technically yes the 2011 correction would be best.

In order of ascending age and accuracy, here are the most important ones:

- NAD 1927
- NAD 1983
- NAD 1983 HARN
- NAD 1983 NSRS2007
- NAD 1983 (2011)
- Coming soon...

NAD 1983 is probably the most common one you'll see, but the most modern, accurate version would be the 2011 update.  I believe this is slated to be [replaced](https://geodesy.noaa.gov/datums/newdatums/index.shtml) in the next year or two.